# .bat to rename all folders labeled X to Y in a sharepoint server

Tags: batch-file, sharepoint, rename

I have a mess of a file tree in a sharepoint with a lot of subfolders that need renaming. I want to rename all subfolders in a directory labeled X to Y. For example, change folders labeled "AY16" to "AY16-17"

This is made more complicated by the folders all being on a sharepoint server, so the file path for the base will something like "http://vaww.visn.portal.va.gov/place/department/section/records" and the subfolders that need renaming will be 2 folders down from there. I don't know if that's compatible with BAT files.

How can I accomplish this with a bat file?

Comment: Best bet would be using PowerShell, a nice answer is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589753/sharepoint-online-powershell-rename-move-file

Comment: I have no experience with Powershell. Is it possible to use the bat rename command on folders over sharepoint?

Comment: I would recommend looking at this link for [mass file manipulation in sharepoint 2010/](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3881/mass-file-manipulation-in-sharepoint-2010/). They pretty much just add the Sharepoint as a network location. I will have a look at a renaming batch for you.

Comment: This should get you where you need to go once you map the sharepoint to a network drive.
`for %%a in (*.*) do ren "%%~a" "%~na -17%%~xa"`